# explicit signature of python function with parameters including 2d numpy arrays

Tags: python, numba

I want to use `@jit` or `@autojit` to speed up my python code, explained here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/harrism/f5707335f40af9463c43

However the example on that page is for pure python functions, whereas my functions are inside a class, and based on some more searching, it appears that in order for this work with class functions, I must provide the explicit signature of the function.

I haven't worked with signatures before, but I understand now how to use them for functions with simple parameters. But I'm getting stuck on how to write them for complicated parameters such as 2D arrays.

Below is my function for which I need an explicit signature.
I really am not sure what to write beyond `@void`...

```
""" Function: train
    Input parameters:
    #X =  shape: [n_samples, n_features]
    #y = classes corresponding to X , y's shape: [n_samples]
    #H = int, number of boosting rounds
    Returns: None
    Trains the model based on the training data and true classes
    """
    #@autojit
    #@void
    def train(self, X, y, H):
           # function code below
           # do lots of stuff...
```

Answer (score 1):

You use the slice syntax on your data type to represent an array. So your example may look something like:

```
from numba import void, int_, float_, jit

...

@jit
class YourClass(object):

    ...

    @void(float_[:, :], int_[:], int_)
    def train(self, X, y, H):
         # X is typed as a 2D float array and y as a 1D int array.
         pass
```

Comment: I've tried what you said but got an error, please see my edited question.

Comment: Yes I forgot - numba classes have to be new style classes, so you have to make your class inherit from object. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks - but that created another error! I've added a second edit to the question.

Comment: Make sure you put pass in the functions if they don't have any executable code.

Comment: All of my functions have a lot of executable code... Not all the  functions return anything but they all do some sort of code execution. This is a fully defined and working class with functions that I've used, I'm only trying to speed it up now.

Comment: In your second edit it looks like your functions are double indented; I don't know how numba does code generation, but perhaps you should try single indenting them. For what it's worth the code you've posted works fine for me if I add pass to the `__init__` and `train` methods.

Comment: could we chat about this? where do you add pass? I tried and now the error is saying    `"%s (don't include 'self')" % (nargs, method.name)) numba.error.NumbaError: Expected 1 argument types in function load_model (don't include 'self') `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56601/discussion-between-user961627-and-dustyrockpyle).